# WinRT how to not have page go up when virtual key board appears Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have an AutoSuggestBox in a XAML Page for a Windows Phone 8.1 app and when i click on the AutoSuggestBox the whole page goes up.  Does anyone know how to disable this feature?

Thanks

Edit:
Here is the code fix, thank you Peter Torr - MSFT.

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += (s, args) =>
            {
                args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = true;
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the [`InputPane.Showing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.showing.aspx) event, and set the `EnsuredFocusedElementInView` property to `true`. This will stop Windows from trying to make the item come into view.